# FFMPEG-PHP example code

Tags: ffmpeg

Can any one help me. I looking to convert a video file into flv using php and ffmpeg.
I have tried some of the existing solution on stackoverflow but with no luck.

`exec('ffmpeg -i Videos/robot.avi -ab 96k -b 700k -ar 44100 -s 640x480 -acodec mp3 Videos/robot.flv');`

This is my code nothing happens when I execute this.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your ffmpeg command works from CLI OK.  If not, get that working first.

If you are trying to output FLV created on-the-fly with PHP and ffmpeg, try this:

```
<?php
  header("video/x-flv");
  passthru('ffmpeg -i Videos/robot.avi -ab 96k -b 700k -ar 44100 -s 640x480 -acodec mp3 Videos/robot.flv');
?>
```

**#### EDIT #####**

Here is a link to ffmpeg documentation that talks about using STDOUT:  http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#TOC41

I think you should be able to do this:

```
<?php
  header("video/x-flv");
  passthru('ffmpeg -i Videos/robot.avi -ab 96k -b 700k -ar 44100 -s 640x480 -acodec mp3 -f flv pipe:');
?>
```

Comment: Hello thank you for the reply. I have tried the code: exec('ffmpeg -i Videos/robot.avi -ab 96k -b 700k -ar 44100 -s 640x480 -acodec mp3 Videos/robot.flv'); using php but nothing happens. The file is not converted. I do not know if passthru is suppose to be a function. I really hope you can assist me.

Comment: passthru() and exec() are almost the same thing, except passthru() will return the results of the command you execute.

Comment: Also, you should modify your command to output the flv to STDOUT instead of writing to a file.

Comment: Wikipedia can explain: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29

Comment: STDOUT is sort of like what a command outputs.  Instead of writing the FLV to a file, it could just output raw data.  You want that b/c you need to send the raw data through PHP to the web browser.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. Studying STDOUT as we speak. Hoe could I implement STDOUT with my exisiting code? thanks

Comment: I have recently tried a simpler exec command: exec('ffmpeg -i Videos/test.avi Videos/test.flv'); This still can not convert the video. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this example: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP

You should get it running in your CLI first before writing a PHP script.

After reading the example it seems like you want to use

```
shell_exec("insert ffmpeg command here");
```

Here's an ffmpeg php class that might be helpful:

https://github.com/olaferlandsen/FFmpeg-PHP-Class

Answer (score 0):

I needed 'sudo' to run it on my local machine.
For video/x-flv you need: "Content-Type: video/x-flv".
My code:

```
<?php

    header("Content-Type: video/x-flv");
    passthru('sudo ffmpeg -i Videos/robot.avi -ab 96k -b 700k -ar 44100 -s 640x480 -acodec mp3 -f flv pipe:');

?>
```