# How to convert flv format into .mp4 format using FFMPEG in php

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Here I am try to convert `.flv` video format into `.mp4` format.
File converted with **zero size** and it's not played.

I need to successfully convert that file using `FFMPEG`.

```
/* Convert type to .mp4 */
exec("ffmpeg -i input.flv -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mp4;");
```

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: How do you know the conversion is "successful"? Did you check the exit code?

Comment: I'm checked. It's converted with 0 bytes.

Comment: Does it work if you run the ffmpeg command manually, unscripted in a command-line interface?

Comment: It's working manually but it's not working using php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `.flv` format video into `.mp4` format

```
header("video/x-flv");
passthru('ffmpeg -i input.flv -ab 96k -b 700k -ar 44100 -s 640x480 -acodec mp3 output.mp4');
```

It's working fine.

Refer: [FFMPEG-PHP example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229465/ffmpeg-php-example-code)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

> exec ("ffmpeg -i input.flv -c:v libx264 output.mp4");

Comment: Also convert 0 Bytes